# Add CiteCount Statistic to Questions, Answers and User Profiles

Tags: feature-request, statistics

Another interesting stat, that could be added to a user's profile, is a count of how many times that user's questions or answers have been **cited by other users in comments, questions, and answers**.

If others, beside myself, consider this an interesting or pertinent statistic, whether cites should garner points or not (to the cited user) would be another topic of discussion.

I suspect a significant percentage of users have cited posts that they have not even voted on, and it is even possible to cite a post you've down-voted. Either way, interestingly, the post was still cite-worthy.

Link popularity is a driving factor in search engine rankings. Also, one measure of a book's influence, is the number of other books who cite that book after it is published. Likewise, "the number of times a Stack Overflow user has been cited" seems to be another pertinent statistic regarding that user's influence.

**One Way To Do It**

Here's one way you might achieve this: each time a post is submitted or updated, the code would simply create an array of all questions and answer IDs cited within the post. The JSON of this record might look like what's output by running the snippet below:

```js
let citeList = {};
// c = comment, q = question, a = answer:
citeList.sourceID = "c/57348372";
citeList.citings = ["q/419458","a/419459/217867"];
console.log(JSON.stringify(citeList,null,1));
```

The JSON outputted above is saying: "In comment 57348372, question 419458 and answer 419459/217867 were cited".

This JSON could be written to a table in the database that acts like a queue. Then, some background process would simply process the queue as needed.

If you added another property to all questions and answers called "citeCount", all this background process would have to do it increment the citeCount for each question or answer cited.

After this, showing citeCount stats at the User Profile level would just be a matter of aggregating the citeCounts on all questions and answers of that user. And, this statistic could be cached for instant retrieval when the user profile page is served (it will be as up-to-date as last cache).

Comment: Could you please clarify value for the site of the feature you suggest? "Interesting stats" does not sound like a good justification.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : I suspect it is about the same value as many of the other statistics already provided in the profiles. How much do those statistics add value to the site? This would probably be about the same value as the majority of those.

Comment: This could probably be written as an [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query, though making it performant enough not to time out on users with a lot of posts could be a challenge/maybe impossible.

Comment: *No*. When you don't know you can at least pretend that the number is greater than zero.

Comment: @RyanM I wouldn't expect the statistic to be real-time (especially at first), although I can imagine technical ways to accomplish almost real-time using background processes on another thread when something is posted or updated.

Comment: Re *"Link popularity is a driving factor in search engine rankings"*: That was the original Google Search, but I don't think that is the case any more (ruined by link and content farms, presumably).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I suspect that honest search algorithms will still attempt to discern "legitimate" link popularity and consider it as a factor in ranking.

Answer (score 10):

I think this metric is about as valuable as the number of times someone copy-pasted code from your answer.

The reasons being:

- Being "cited" is simply "someone bothered to credit you for this"
- There's no in-built tracking mechanism for this, and a text editor somewhere on someone's desk with all of the citations can't report back
- It's more the case that people simply *won't* cite your answer or link back to it or attribute it, violating CC-by-SA (but realistically speaking [only we, the actual copyright holders could do anything about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/175248))

Comment: Totally agree on value :). Note that there is somewhat related information with "share" (and even badges for using such links) - so in theory it is possible to at least make that stats publicly visible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the share badge is fundamentally broken...I've not linked out my answers to any other major platform and yet somehow I'm getting badges for those @AlexeiLevenkov.

Comment: I wasn't referring to offsite cites. I clearly said: "cited by other users in comments, questions, and answers" (meaning from StackOverflow.com).

Comment: @Makoto I'm pretty sure any time "share" link (one with you user ID) is used (irrespective where it comes from - SO or outside) it counts. So if you ever used "Share" button to get a link to include in a comment it will count toward the badge when on clicks on the link.

Comment: though... i do think it'd be nice to have data on copying, given they're collecting the data and not currently sharing it with us.